# How to insert an arrow under a table in LaTeX?

Tags: text, latex, arrows

[image: n]

I want to create a table in LaTeX and the add an arrow in the next line, but the arrow should be under the second column and then another newline  with the number 10 as shown in the picture below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the construction in a `tabular` or `array`, and use `\multicolumn`s to provide the appropriate rules.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ *{6}{c} }
  \cline{2-6}
  A \qquad & 
    \multicolumn{1}{|c}{\phantom{0}} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{|c}{1} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{|c}{\phantom{0}} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{|c}{\phantom{0}} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\phantom{0}} \\
  \cline{2-6}
           &       & $\downarrow$ \\
           &       &      10
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```